# ordering of date on xaxis after format

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot:

I am using scale_x_date  to get the format to the dates "MON DD" on the axis below but I don't want to change the date ONLY the format. So I'd like "Jan 01", "Jan 08", "Jan 15", "Jan 22" on the x axis instead of "Jan 04", "Jan 11" etc..... Is that possible?

```
 library(scales)
  library(ggplot2)
    d = data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2016-01-22", "2016-01-01")),value= c(1,2))
    ggplot(d, aes(
      x=date, 
      #x= factor(format(as.Date(date),"%b %d"),levels =  unique(   format(as.Date(date),"%b %d") ) ),  
      y = value,group=1))+
      geom_point() + scale_x_date(date_label="%b %d", date_breaks = "1 week") +
      geom_line()+xlab("date")
```

Comment: why'd you change them to a factor? `ggplot(d, aes(date, value)) + geom_point() + geom_line()+ scale_x_date(date_label="%b %d")`

Comment: @hrbrmstr See edit.  I don't want to change the date shown. I only want to change the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the default ticks are as they appear, but this should do the trick:

```
dts <- seq(from = as.Date("2016-01-01"),to = as.Date("2016-01-28"), by = 7)
ggplot(d, aes(x=date, y = value,group=1)) +
  geom_point() + scale_x_date(labels=format(dts,"%b %d"), breaks = dts) +
  geom_line()+xlab("date")
```